# If/else with 4 variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables

What's the correct way to make sure users input information exactly how I want it, or else echo a statement with the correct expectation? I have a bash script that has 4 variables that require specific forms of entry, but I can't figure out how to check their input.

These are the variables I have that I use to complete my command:

```
read -p "Enter ID: " ID #SONGID can only be 10 digits long
read -p "Enter directory to search in e.g ab,cd,ef: " DIR #Directories are two letters and range from a-z
read -p "This abbreviation needs to match previous choice e.g ab, cd, ef: " FILE
read -p "Enter date of file e.g 20140503 or 201405*: " DATE
```

Right now the way I have it written the script continues no matter what.

```
SONGID="10"
if [ $(echo "SONGID" | grep -E "[0-10") ] && 
    echo "Song ID good"
else
    echo "ID needs to be 10 digits"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: You probably need something like `grep -E '^[0-9]{10}$'` to match exactly 10 digits from 0 to 9.  Basically, though, you devise commands similar to those you show to validate the data.  Consider using a function to do the job.

Comment: FYI, it's conventional for non-exported, non-builtin variable names to be lowercase. Environment variables are all-uppercase, sure, but that doesn't mean everything should be; by following this convention you don't risk overwriting or shadowing environment variables by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern similar to the following. Pure Bash. You're sure that when you leave the `while` loop the data has been validated by the corresponding function—so in case of problems, you'll have to blame that function, not the structure of the program<sup>1</sup>.

```
#!/bin/bash

validate_ID() {
    # Success if and only if $1 is a string of 10 digits
    [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]{10}$ ]]
}

validate_dir() {
    # Success if and only if $1 is a string of 2 letters in the range [a-z]
    [[ $1 =~ ^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]{2}$ ]]
    # Hard-coded here for security, since depending on locales, other characters
    # would pass, e.g., é. Try it: [[ é =~ [a-z] ]]; echo $?
}

validate_file() {
    # I didn't understand the requirements... this always succeeds for now
    return 0
}

validate_date() {
    # Don't know how you want to validate this... this always succeeds for now
    return 0
}

while :; do
    IFS= read -rep "Enter ID: " songID
    history -s -- "$songID"
    validate_ID "$songID" && break
    echo "Bad ID"
done

while :; do
    IFS= read -rep "Enter directory to search in e.g ab,cd,ef: " dir #Directories are two letters and range from a-z
    history -s -- "$dir"
    validate_dir "$dir" && break
    echo "Bad dir"
done

while :; do
    IFS= read -rep "This abbreviation needs to match previous choice e.g ab, cd, ef: " file
    history -s -- "$file"
    validate_file "$file" && break
    echo "Bad file"
done

while :; do
    IFS= read -rep "Enter date of file e.g 20140503 or 201405*: " date
    history -s -- "$date"
    validate_date "$date" && break
    echo "Bad date"
done
```

The `history` commands: each command insert the value read into history, so that user will be able to retrieve former values by using the up arrow (try with and without)—notice the `-e` flag to the `read` command to use readline. TAB-completion works on filenames.

*Note.* There are two validation functions that don't do their job for now; I didn't exactly understand how you want to validate the data.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some other REPL designs can fail, e.g.,

```
while read a; do
    validate "$a" && break
    echo "$a is invalid"
done
```

seems fine, but will fail if there's an error in the read, e.g., the user could enter arbitrary data, press Ctrl-D a couple of times and you'll have that arbitrary data in the variable `a`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Changed it a bit to include additional variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a variable before you do your checks

```
INPUT_STATUS=good
```

then do your checks, changing the variable when you find an error

```
case $SONGID in
  [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
    # this matches when song IDs are 10 digits -- do nothing here
    ;;
  *)
    # this matches when song IDs are not 10 digits -- we're bad now
    INPUT_STATUS=bad
    ;;
esac

if [ $INPUT_STATUS = 'good' ]; then
  echo "Song ID is good."
else
  echo "Song IDs need to be exactly 10 digits."
fi
```

Don't be tempted to set `INPUT_STATUS=good` for each time a check succeeds.

The use of the `case` statement allows us to specify a pattern to match against `SONGID` that [conforms to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13).  Alternatively, a modern shell might allow us to use [a more sophisticated regex in the if statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005d_005d).  Using a pattern that the shell can work with gives us the added benefit of being tremendously faster than calling out to an external program like `grep` to do the matching.

Comment: FYI, `==` isn't valid inside POSIX `[ ]`. It's supported as a GNU extension (and by several other recent shells and `test` implementations as well), but to be compatible with baseline POSIX systems you should use `=` for string comparisons.

Comment: ...also, doing the comparisons natively in the shell, as with `case $SONGID in [0-9]|10) echo "Song ID good"; *) INPUT_STATUS=bad;; esac` will be much, **much** faster than shelling out to grep every time.

Comment: You need to fix the `grep` regex; it is broken as written in the question (and therefore also when copied into your answer).  Unfortunately, it is not hard to be caught out by such problems (it happens to me occasionally).  OTOH, you should _not_ get down-votes from it.

Comment: I'll try to update to be POSIX compliant.  And to avoid process activation with a call to grep, but apparently the pattern needs to match, effectively, [[:digit:]]{10} (as his comment says "SONGID can only be 10 digits long"), and {{case}} uses the basic shell pattern matching, which I think of as "file globbing", and that isn't sophisticated enough to specify that pattern, so there may not be a way to do the pattern matching in-shell, i.e., without calling out to grep.

Comment: Actually, while specifying 10 digits is ugly, it's still quite possible.  I'll update my answer.